# MouseEvents from JComponents

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, listener

I wrote a game using swing and I have problems with the mouse events.

I have a Panel that extends JFrame and it adds a Board Object, which contains "Paintable" objects in a list. These objects contain other lists with paintable objects and it keeps calling the subobjects until it reaches the lowest object where it actually draws it.

```
public interface Paintable {
   void paint(Graphics2D g);
}
```

I wrote a small example to show what I mean:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    List<Patch> patches = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
        mainPanel.addPatches();

        mainPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("out");

                // I want to access the clicked object here
            }
        });

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(1000, 800);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addPatches() {
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            patches.add(new Patch(random.nextInt(1000), random.nextInt(800), 30, 30));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        patches.forEach(patch -> patch.paintComponent(g));
    }
}
```

Class where it draws the objects:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Patch extends JComponent {

    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public Patch(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("in");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to access the clicked Patch in the MainPanel in the mouseClicked Event. How can I do that?

I also tried adding a listener to the Patch class but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you checked the sizes of your Patch components, you'd likely find them to be 0, 0 or 1,1, regardless, they are very small since their preferredSizes are very small. I suggest that rather than making Patch extend JComponent that you instead make it a logical non-component entity, and give it mouse click properties by using Shape derived objects, objects that are held in a collection such as an ArrayList by the MainPanel object, and that are notified of possible mouse presses within a MouseListener added to MainPanel.

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Color[] COLORS = { Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.blue,
            Color.green, Color.cyan, Color.magenta };
    private List<Patch> patches = new ArrayList<>();
    Random random = new Random();

    public MainPanel() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // use mousePressed not mouseClicked

                // go backwards for correct handling of overlaps
                for (int i = patches.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (patches.get(i).contains(e.getPoint())) {
                        System.out.println("pressed");
                        e.consume();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("out");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
        mainPanel.addPatches();

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(1000, 800);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addPatches() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Color c = COLORS[random.nextInt(COLORS.length)];
            patches.add(new Patch(random.nextInt(1000), random.nextInt(800), 30, 30, c));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        patches.forEach(patch -> patch.draw(g));
    }
}

class Patch {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Color color;
    private Rectangle rectangle;

    public Patch(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
        rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public boolean contains(Point p) {
        return rectangle.contains(p);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Color oldColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        g.setColor(oldColor);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're right, they are all very small.
In the real game I didn't extend JComponent though, the class Patch contains a Polygone for the size and paints that.

Here is the code from the main project:
http://pastebin.com/AKTbR8aV (too long to paste)

GameObject only contains a String name and getName().

Comment: Thanks for the example. So basically I add a method contains() and iterate over all objects? I have three nested lists / objects and I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: @MWin123: That's the subject of a different question.